# How to dynamically load rows in enyo when using the Repeater kind?

Tags: enyo

I was able to add a load more section on the bottom row and successfully have a load more working using `setCount`. Except it reloads everything (as its suppose to) with no way of maintaining the state of where you were before load more was clicked. So I tried using `renderRow`, but that does not work because it only refreshes rows that already exists (in my case the rows to be loaded have not been loaded into memory yet). I don't see anything immediately useful in the docs. Anyone encountered this problem or have an idea of how to solve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to update this answer with something more complete but what you need to do is find the index of the topmost row before you add your new content and then scroll that row back into view after you update.  Something like that should do what you want.  I think there were some discussions back on the old developer.palm.com forums from Enyo 1 days that discuss the technique.  Should still be applicable to Enyo 2.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I have been trying to do. I found a good way. Except its not working as expected. I am trying to use `itemAtIndex` to obtain where I was last and scroll there using the scroller my repeater is in. But I am getting an error : `Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of null`. Is that something necessary for Scroller?

Comment: Actually I figured it out. I always seem to forget that my `item` is within a few controls, so I wasn't getting that and it wasn't forwarding it to where it should be. Thanks though :)

Comment: Can you answer your own question with your code sample so others can use it?  Sorry I never got a chance to update!